# Prove that $OM=ON$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Consider $\Delta ABC$ has $AB=AC\text{ and } \angle BAC=90^o$. Let $O$ with radius $\dfrac{AB}2$. The secant $DE$ such that $CE$ always goes through $OB$.  $CO \cap BD=M;CO \cap BE= N$. Prove that $OM=ON$

[image]

---

To prove $OM=ON$ we need prove $MANB$ is parallelogram $(OA=OB)$

We need to prove $\angle MAB=\angle ABN\rightarrow \angle MAC=\angle BAE=\angle BDE=\angle CDM$

I dont know how to prove this. I tried to prove some similar triangles but failed.

Comment: Do you know projective geometry?

Comment: If you play around with the applet you might realize that the AB = AC criterion is superfluous and can be dropped, and thus doesn't actually need factor into any proof and so building the proof around it might be a dead end.

Comment: @MariaMazur: No i dont. Have you got another idea?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3160696/prove-that-bc-b-1c-1-b-2c-2-are-concurrent/3162290#3162290

Answer (score 1):

[image]

hint: if you can approve TE pass O , then the problem is solved.

Comment: potentially solve with symmetry?